# How To Stop Bottle.py Auto Reloading

Tags: python-2.7, bottle

Im quite new to bottle.py
I got problem with `run(reloader=True)`
Is there a way to stop the server? Hitting `ctr+c` didnt stop the server.
By the way im on linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In linux you can kill the process.

Find it:

```
ps -ef|grep python
```

And you kill the process using the first number in the line of the process:

```
sudo kill 99999
```

This is for Ubuntu.

The port could show as `in use` when you restart and that was resolved in stackoverflow but I don't remember where so you will have to look for it.

Comment: basically kill python process?

Comment: Yes, that's it. The process you started.